# how to add class to list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

```js
 
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.href; 
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        if (this.href === path) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="a.php">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.php">Bs</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.php">C  </a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the class="active" in list items on click.

Comment: You're saying you want the class to be added on click, but I think what you mean, based on your snippet, is on page load. Would that be a correct assumption?

Comment: yes on page load i want the active to change on that page .

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="a" ><a href="a.php">A</a></li>

 Using $('#a').attr('class', 'active')
```

Output:

```
    <li id="a" class='active' ><a href="a.php">A</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're checking the li element for its href property, which doesn't exist. You need to check the a tag inside of the li element for the href property like this:

```
if ($(this).find('a').attr('href') === path) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$(this).toggleClass('class1 class2')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change an active class and html pages this would be an effective way to do this.If you just want to change the active class use only the first 4 lines of code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $(".nav li").click(function() {        
    $(".nav li.active").removeClass("active");      
    $(this).addClass("active");       
    if($(this).attr('id')=="yourfirstlinkid"){           
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="yoursite" height="90% width="90%" ></object>';       
    }else if($(this).attr('id')=="otherid"){        
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="othersite"></object>';                
    }else{                 
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<div/>';
    }
        });

    });
```

And then all you need to do to your html is

```
 <ul class="nav">
  <li class="active" id="whateveryouwant"><a href="#anything you want">A</a></li>
   <li id="whateveryouwant" ><a href="#anything you want">Bs</a></li>
   <li id="whateveryouwant"><a href="#anything you want">C</a></li>
    </ul> 
<div align= "center" id="content"></div>
```

Another thing I want to add is never use herf for a nav bar because the navbar js code will change never allowing it to change it's current active class.

Comment: do any of our answers work for you please let us know